# save data for an HTML element such that it can be accessed later

Tags: javascript

Everything I've read says do not save custom properties or attributes to HTML DOM Elements. So I'm trying to figure out how else I should save properties/attributes for an element such that I can access them later.

Originally I was thinking of using the element as the key in a hash but JS converts hash keys to string so that won't work.

Use case:

```
function do1(element)
{
    var w = element.style.width;
    element.style.width = "200px";

    // i want to save the w variable for this element somewhere/somehow
}

function do2(element)
{
    // i want to be able to get the w variable i saved earlier for the element
}
```

I thought of using the `element`'s `ID` but the `element` won't always have an `ID` that I can use and I can't set one because there **might** be other JS that dynamically sets `ID`s for elements.

Comment: why don't you create the element's `w` property ? (`element.w = xyz`)

Comment: everything I read says that is a bad idea. for example, what if the DOM spec is updated and the `w` property becomes used for something else.

Comment: Then use something less probe to be changed (element.__myOwnWidthValue) or use dataset as proposed by ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)? They're specifically intended for storing extra data on an element.

Comment: I need something IE 8 friendly.

Comment: Maybe you could use [a polyfill for dataset support](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#dataset-property-for-use-with-custom-data--attributes)?